# Array output and date format

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to what I need to do.

I have a mysql database with a field of date values called 'StartDate' which is formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

So, I have connected to the database using -

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_myEventDates ORDER BY `StartDate` ASC" );
```

I would like to group the events by the month, so for example there are 10 events in June, then 12 events in July -

I have used a foreach loop and tested several methods to output the date and used var_dump but I am unsure of how to manipulate the results.

Example One:

```
$event_id = $myevent->StartDate;
// var dump from event id gives me 
string(10) "2013-04-04"
```

Example two:

```
$event_id = $myevent->StartDate;  
$dateArray = getdate(strtotime($event_id));
$mythingmonth = array($dateArray['mon']);
foreach ($mythingmonth as $monthsplit =>$myvalue) {
var_dump($myvalue);
//var dump from myvalue this 
int(4)
}
```

I am 100% sure I am going about this the wrong way, I've tried searching and trying but I am lost with it - so if any pointers or suggestions for what to have a look at, that would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT Month(startdate),count(id) as nrOfEvents
FROM wp_myEventDates
GROUP BY Month(startdate)
```

but reading your question again, I'm not sure if that's what you want. Could you describe the expected result ?

EDIT :

if your events run on several years, it may be better to use this :

```
SELECT Month(startdate),Year(startdate),count(id) as nrOfEvents
FROM wp_myEventDates
GROUP BY Month(startdate),Year(startdate)
```

Comment: Hi @Bartdude - I need to generate a list of months that have events in them and make a link to the right page - I'll have a look at what you've suggested - thank you!

Comment: The you could probably make use of my query for a start. It should only return months with an event starting during that month, and the number of associated event.

Comment: HI @Bartude - Will try this later, I've been asked to jump on something else quickly - thank you for responding again.

Comment: Hi @Bartdude - sorry, misspelt your name before! - that looks like it works great!["Month(StartDate)"]=> string(1) "4" ----- ["nrOfEvents"]=> string(2) "12" Really appreciate your help - I just need to learn how to loop through now :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not so clear with question, but if you are trying to group data base on query reslut i have example for you here,

```
$event_id = array ("2013-04-04","2013-04-04","2013-05-04","2013-04-04","2013-06-04");
foreach($event_id as $value)
{
   $value = explode('-',$value);
   $month[$value[1]][] = 'hi'; // you can add ur event name here instead of 'hi'
}
var_dump($month);
```

vardump($month) give you below output

```
array
 '04' => 
   array
     0 => string 'hi' (length=2)
     1 => string 'hi' (length=2)
     2 => string 'hi' (length=2)
 '05' => 
   array
     0 => string 'hi' (length=2)
 '06' => 
   array
     0 => string 'hi' (length=2)
```

and vardump($month['04']); will give you below result

```
array
 0 => string 'hi' (length=2)
 1 => string 'hi' (length=2)
 2 => string 'hi' (length=2)
```

Instead of 'hi' in foreach to can add event name which is result of query and you can collect event by months using this type of array

Comment: Hi @Kashyap - I will give this a go as well, I've been asked to jump on another project for this afternoon - thank you for responding to me.

Comment: Hi @Kashyap - I tried your solution, but for some reason I could not get it to work, it did not like the [] - Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings - I could get it to work on a plain PHP file though - I am a newb though - but I really appreciate your help. So far Bartdude solution seems to work