# object(stdClass) Array and returning values

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I seem to be stuck again! - I asked this question on friday which @Bartdude was great with answering - [Array output and date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733886/array-output-and-date-format)

This outputted an array like this -

```
[0]=> object(stdClass)#270 (3) 
{ 
["Month(StartDate)"]=> string(1) "4" 
["Year(StartDate)"]=> string(4) "2013" 
["nrOfEvents"]=> string(2) "12" 
} 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#176 (3) 
{ 
["Month(StartDate)"]=> string(1) "5" 
["Year(StartDate)"]=> string(4) "2013" 
["nrOfEvents"]=> string(2) "19" 
} 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#114 (3) 
{ 
["Month(StartDate)"]=> string(1) "6" 
["Year(StartDate)"]=> string(4) "2013" 
["nrOfEvents"]=> string(2) "12" 
} 
}
```

Then after some searching through Stack Exchange I found this would return nrofEvents -

```
echo $results[0]->nrOfEvents
// Outputs - 12
```

I am struggling to understand how to access ["Month(StartDate)"] in the array in a foreach loop.

My end goal is to achieve a table of months that has a month name, for example

| **Mar** (12) | **Apr**(19) | **Jun**(12) |

| **Jul**(3) | **Aug**(4) | **Sep**(5) |

Any help in helping me understand would be fantastic and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($array as $object) {
   echo $object->{'Month(StartDate)'}, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: HI @Silkfire - thank you, out of all the solutions I found yours easiest to work with to my knowledge level, with a couple of 'if' statements I have been able to get it roughly where I want it to be. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This allows to access `Month(StartDate)`:

```
$results[0]->{'Month(StartDate)'}
```

But you would better be using arrays

Comment: Hi @arnaud576875 - yours is awesome as well, thank you, I guess I got a bit stumped because I didn't know about adding the curly brackets!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Month(startdate) AS month, count(id) as nrOfEvents
FROM wp_myEventDates
GROUP BY Month(startdate)
```

You will be able to the month value by:

```
echo $results[0]->month
// Outputs - 4
```

Comment: Hi @benomite I honestly thought I tried that - I must have mistyped something in my many confusing moments throughout this thing I have to do! thank you for your answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$array = [array of dates]
$formats = array();

foreach($array as $key => $object)
{
    $formats[] = date('M', $array[$key]->{Month(StartDate)}) . ' (' . $array[$key]->nrOfEvents . ')';
}

$formats = implode(' | ', $formats);
```

HOWEVER: You should seriously consider renaming your array values. `(` and `)` are not valid for variable names.

Comment: Hi @Phil Cross your answer is awesome and pretty much did what I needed to do, however I found silkfire's answer easier (for my knowledge) level to work with - I am however when I get some time going to play with your suggestion more! - thank you.

Comment: Not a problem :) Enjoy! P.S: @Andy don't forget to accept silkfire's answer, and maybe upvote? :)

Comment: Hi @Phil Cross - I can't upvote yet :( - only another 3 newb questions and I'll be able to! - thanks again :)